# Detectar cuando la app se haya cargado completamente en ionic/angular con splashscreen

Tags: angular, ionic

Qué tal chicos? Tengo un problema, en mi proyecto de ionic he creado un splasscreen en mi app, quiero que ese splashscreen se mantenga activa mientras la aplicacion se inicialice completamente.

app.component.ts

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
```

estoy importanto timer para controlar el tiempo que el splashscreen este activo

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
showSplash = true;

initializeApp() {
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.statusBar.styleDefault();
  this.splashScreen.hide();

  timer(10000).subscribe(() => this.showSplash = false); -> aqui esta el problema
});
```

}
}

Lo que yo quiero es que

> El SplashScreen se mantenga activa hasta que la aplicacion se inicialice completamente y no por un tiempo definido por ti

Comment: no es necesario el timer dado que `this.splashScreen.hide();` lo oculta. Ademas esta instrucción esta dentro de `this.platform.ready()` lo que implica que se oculta justo cuando ya todo a cargado. Si lo que necesitas es aumentar el tiempo en que  muesta el SplasScreen debes hacerlo en el `config.xml`. Por lo tanto lo unico que debes hacer es solo sacar la instrucción `this.showSplash = false;` fuera del timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque no controlas el tiempo que quieres que tu splash este activo en con `<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />` en el archivo `config.xml` esto lo que hará es que mostrara el splash hasta que se agote el tiempo.